# Extracting metadata like age and resolution from XYZ tilesets using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, metadata, xyz

I'm using PyQGIS to develop a standalone application. I need to get metadata from the current visible tile, such as the age and resolution of the satellite image.

Is this possible?

It doesn't necessarily have to be in PyQGIS, it's fine if I have to use an external API or something.

Answer (score 2):

No, unless the tile provider has provided that metadata in the tile image file.

I just manually downloaded a couple of satellite image tiles from two of the major satellite image tile providers and there is no such metadata in the tiles.

Given that many of the tiles will be composites of several satellite images in order to get good cloud-free pictures, the age and resolution of the source satellite image is not precisely defined.

Proper satellite imagery sources will let you get the metadata for image products so that you can trace your analysis right back to the satellite orbit number if you need it, but working out the original source or sources for a given tile in a tile service is next to impossible. There's no metadata in the tile and too much processing has probably occurred between satellite source and tile image.